How to display .tiff file on leaflet map website on mobile devices?
My question is why on computers the site works fine, but when I try to open the site on mobile devices such as tablets or phones, the moment the .tif file should be displayed on the map, the site gets crushed. I read that Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF would be a good solution, but I want to use the file that is in the project folder instead of on google cloud or AWS. So what is causing this error and can I solve it somehow? I tried changing the resolution of the .tiff file even to 50 as shown in the code, but that doesn't help either.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <style>
      #map {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster-layer-for-leaflet"></script>
    <script>
      // initialize leaflet map
      var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 5);

      // add OpenStreetMap basemap
      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
          maxZoom: 64
      }).addTo(map);

      var url_to_geotiff_file = "odm_orthophoto.tif";

      fetch(url_to_geotiff_file)
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(arrayBuffer => {
          parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer).then(georaster => {
            console.log("georaster:", georaster);
            var layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
                georaster: georaster,
                opacity: 0.7,
                resolution: 50
            });
            layer.addTo(map);

            map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());

        });
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>


